# Getting the first and last score from the Player ID

Tags: postgresql, self-join

I'm trying to get the first and last record from this table:

```
CREATE TABLE record(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  player_id BIGINT,
  score INT
);

INSERT INTO record(player_id,score) VALUES(603,15);
INSERT INTO record(player_id,score) VALUES(603,5);
INSERT INTO record(player_id,score) VALUES(604,15);
INSERT INTO record(player_id,score) VALUES(604,10);
INSERT INTO record(player_id,score) VALUES(604,15);
INSERT INTO record(player_id,score) VALUES(612,20);
INSERT INTO record(player_id,score) VALUES(612,5);
INSERT INTO record(player_id,score) VALUES(612,10);
INSERT INTO record(player_id,score) VALUES(612,15);
```

How do I get the first and last score with one single row for `player_id`? So, the table will look like this:

```
|==========|============|===============|
|player_id | first_score| last_score    |
|==========|============|===============|
|603       | 15         | 5             |
|604       | 15         | 15            |
|612       | 20         | 15            |
|==========|============|===============|
```

Here's what I have so far in DB-Fiddle, and I can't seem to get it right:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gLuJ1dbwg5Eor3SUrubpbe/1

Comment: There is no such thing as a "first" or "last" row in a relational database unless you have some expression that you can use to define a sort order. Which column in your sample data defines that sort order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) question which is typically done using [`distinct on ()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) in Postgres.

You need one query to get the first score and one to get the last (assuming that "first" and "last" is defined through the `id` column)

```
select fs.player_id, 
       fs.score as first_score, 
       ls.score as last_score
from (
  -- "first" score per player
  select distinct on (player_id) *
  from record
  order by player_id, id 
) fs
  left join (
    -- "last" score per player
    select distinct on (player_id) *
    from record
    order by player_id, id desc
  ) ls on ls.player_id = fs.player_id
order by player_id;
```

Another option (but probably less efficient) is to use a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) that numbers the scores per player. Then use filtered aggregation to "pivot" the result into two columns.

```
with numbered as (
  select player_id, 
         row_number() over (partition by player_id order by id) as rn_first,
         row_number() over (partition by player_id order by id desc) as rn_last,
         score
  from record
)
select player_id, 
       max(score) filter (where rn_first = 1) as first_score,
       max(score) filter (where rn_last = 1) as last_score
from numbered
where rn_first = 1 or rn_last = 1
group by player_id
order by player_id;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b78aaf6fc94e9ccb6b8fbcb9143c0b03)

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it... but let me know if there is a more efficient way to do this:

```
SELECT
  first_scores.player_id,
  first_score,
  last_score
FROM
(
  SELECT
    record.player_id,
    record.id,
    score AS first_score
  FROM record
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      player_id,
      MIN(record.id) AS min_record_id
    FROM record
    GROUP BY player_id
    ORDER BY player_id  
  ) AS min_scores
  ON min_record_id = record.id
) AS first_scores
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT
    record.player_id,
    record.id,
    score AS last_score
  FROM record
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      player_id,
      MAX(record.id) AS max_record_id
    FROM record
    GROUP BY player_id
    ORDER BY player_id  
  ) AS max_scores
  ON max_record_id = record.id  
) AS last_scores ON first_scores.player_id = last_scores.player_id
```

Here's the DB fiddle:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gLuJ1dbwg5Eor3SUrubpbe/4